# How to implement GetURL / GetTooltip for the CHyperlink Control?

Tags: visual-c++, hyperlink, mfc, tooltip

[`CHyperlink`](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/117333/making-the-cmfclinkctrl-class-more-developer-frien) has:

- [`SetURL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfclinkctrl-class?view=msvc-170#seturl)
- [`SetTooltip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcbutton-class?view=msvc-170#settooltip)

But it does not seem to have `Get` equivalents?

This class is derived from `CMFCLinkCtrl`.

How do we implement these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `GetURL`

I delved into the source code for `CMFCLinkCtrl::SetURL`:

```
void CMFCLinkCtrl::SetURL(LPCTSTR lpszURL)
{
    if (lpszURL == NULL)
    {
        m_strURL.Empty();
    }
    else
    {
        m_strURL = lpszURL;
    }
}
```

All I had to do was add a public method to the class I derived from `CHyperlink` to return the value of `m_strURL`:

```
CString GetURL()
{
    return m_strURL;
}
```

---

### `GetToolTip`

The [`CMFCLinkCtrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfclinkctrl-class?view=msvc-170) is derived from [`CMFCButton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcbutton-class?view=msvc-170) which has a [`GetToolTipCtrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcbutton-class?view=msvc-170#gettooltipctrl) method. This returns a **reference** to the underlying tooltip control. As a result, we can do this to get the tooltip text:

```
CString GetToolTip()
{
    CString strToolTip;
    GetToolTipCtrl().GetText(strToolTip, this);
    return strToolTip;
}
```

Comment: <del>add a public method to CHyperlink</del> => add a public method to **the class I derived from** CHyperlink